# Позиционирование фиксированного блока после прокрутки страницы

Tags: css, веб-программирование, position

Есть один блок, который можно увидеть не сразу, лишь после  прокрутки страницы. Нужно сделать так, чтобы после появления этого блока он стал "fixed".

```
.block{
    margin-top:30%;
    width:40%;
    float:right;    
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: в чем проблема? что уже пытались сделать?

Comment: когда я делал, блок сразу был закреплен, а нужно, чтоб после прокрутки

Comment: @АнтонПерехрест добавьте в текст вопроса HTML и CSS, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то вроде такого jQuery (http://jsfiddle.net/5n5MA/2/)

```
var fixmeTop = $('.fixme').offset().top;       

$(window).scroll(function() {                  

  var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop(); 
  if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) {           
    $('.fixme').css({                        
        position: 'fixed',
        top: '0',
        left: '0'
    });
  } else {                                   
    $('.fixme').css({                        
        position: 'static'
    });
  }

});
```

[по мотивам](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850271/how-to-make-div-fixed-after-you-scroll-to-that-div)